# access sshfs directory with gui

Tags: permissions, gui, sshfs

I mounted a remote directory on my computer and it seems fine - I can cd to it or open an editor from the terminal and see all the files etc. But when it try to access it from the gui menu access is denied. I know I can do `sudo -i nautilus` but that works only for one window/program at a time.

Is there a way allow a global access, so every time I start a program (not from the command line) it will have access to my directory?

Comment: I believe you need to give the remote folder access to the xorg for the gui to work. or perhaps the other way around

Comment: @ravery how I do that?

Comment: I don't know. ti sudo a GUI root  had to be added to xhost or something like that

Comment: *"I mounted a remote directory on my computer and it seems fine"* please [edit] your question to summarize *how* you mounted it, including any mount options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the remote folder as follows:

`sshfs user@myremotecomputer:/remote/path /local/path -C -p 9876 -o allow_other`

Where -p 9876 stands for the port number, -C enables compression and -o allow_other grants non-rooted users read/write access. The allow_other option is disabled by default. To enable it, uncomment the line user_allow_other in /etc/fuse.conf to enable non-root users to use the allow_other mount option. The -p option is not necessary if the standard ssh port (22) is being used, and the -C option only if you want compression.